# How to change and render a source array from a child component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have an array in the parent component that I render to the template, I need that when I click on a link to a vue-router with the dynamic attribute id, I have opened a new component with only that element of the array that matches the id. My code is not working.
Parent component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="addPost">Add</button>
        <div v-for="item, index in arr" :key="item.id">
            <p>{{item.title}}</p>
            <router-link :to="'/blog/' + item.id">Link</router-link>
        </div
        <router-view :arr="arr"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    import Post from './components/Post'
    components: {
        'app-post': Post
    },
    data() {
       return {
           arr: []
       }
   },
   methods: {
       addPost() {
           this.arr.push({
                title: this.title,
                id: Math.Random()
           })
       }
   }
}
```

Child component:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item, index in arr" :key="index">
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
   props: {
       arr: Array
   },
   created() {
       return this.arr.find(item => {
           return item.id === this.$route.params.id
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a proper [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is not clear what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use params in your router-link like this

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'blog', params: { id: ${item.id}}}">User</router-link>
```

then in child you can access

```
   let paramID =  this.$route.params.id
```